# What are the advantages and disadvantages of voyager laravel framework?

Tags: laravel, admin, panel, laravel-5.7

I have a project in **laravel 5.7**. I am going to use the **voyager admin panel** template. But I don't know about it. so I have some questions,

1. Is it suitable for a big project?
2. Is it conflicts with my existing project?
3. It is easy to change or modify?

Comment: Questions 1 and 3 are entirely opinion-based, so off-topic. Question 2 depends on your specific project, which we know nothing about, so also off-topic.

Comment: Yes but I want general cons and pros of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**My answers **

**for question 1 :**

1. As I used `voyager` admin panel for my `transcription` web application project, it is complicated to configure every page in admin panel . For simple blog based or any small projects , I would suggest voyager.  But for large project , I will suggest any other admin panel like `AdminLTE` which is totally customization .
   But still voyager is easy admin panel with `CRUD` options.

**For Question 2 :**

No. As voyager is totally a package which can be installed from `composer`, it won't change the existing folders. But you can customize it .

**For Question 3 :**

Yes it is . Once you managed to get how it works, You can go with voyager for all kind of projects.  It is easy to build a admin panel with voyager than others.

**Conclusion:**

If you are lazy to build another admin panel , and you want things to be simplified , you can go with voyager.  It is easy , I mean very easy .